# How can I customize android CalendarView cell?

Tags: android, android-studio, cell, calendarview

I want to customize android CalendarView like this:

[image]

The layout is not different of android native calendar view. 
Only each cell's layout is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TimesSquare for Android](https://github.com/square/android-times-square), a third party library and customize it as you want.

I hope it helps.